# Why is the iOS6 simulator slow to delete an application?

Tags: xcode, ios6, ios-simulator

I stopped the running process from Xcode, closed the background app.

When I start closing it the simulator hangs for about 20 seconds before prompting "Delete __app?"

Answer (score 0):

Try to repair disk permissions. I had a similar issue with the simulator buggin out after an XCode crashed and repairing solved it.

**Edit:**
This actually just happened to me. I was also not able to connect to the simulator. I ended up doing this:

- Close XCode
- Delete the simulator folder `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/X.X/`
- Delete the `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` folder
- Repair disk permissions (did not work without this step)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to delete apps in a faster way by following these steps

1. iOS Simulator
2. Reset Content and Settings...